# Pandas Group_by using multiple keys, but only want to specify outer key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have just started learning about pandas. I am doing a project with video games sales data. The data frame I'm working with looks like this:

```
    Rank    Name          Platform     Year    Genre    Publisher   Global_Sales    
0   1   Wii Sports          Wii      2006.0   Sports    Nintendo      41.49     
1   2   Super Mario Bros.   NES      1985.0   Platform  Nintendo      29.08     
2   3   Mario Kart Wii      Wii      2008.0   Racing    Nintendo      15.85
```

I want to get the global sales of a specific year, separated by genre, like this:

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ghme.png)

So, I decided to group up the data using groupby():

```
data.groupby(['Year','Genre'])
```

I want to then get the subgroup under Year '2008.0', so I used get_group() followed by .sum() to get the global sales per genre:

```
data.groupby(['Year','Genre']).get_group(2008.0).sum()
```

However, the above code doesn't work because I have grouped the data by two keys, and Python now requires me to pass a tuple that specifies a year and a genre, as the argument for get_group().

Is there anyway for me to only specify the outer key only, AKA the 'Year' key? Because I want to have all genre displayed in a similar fashion as shown in the picture above.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
df.groupby(['Year', 'Genre']).sum('Global_Sales')
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter out before grouping

```
df.query('Year == 2008').groupby(['Year','Genre']).sum()
```